# AMD-Vi: completion-wait loop time out during OpenMandriva Lx 3.0 alongside Windows 10

Tags: mandriva

I'm trying to install OpenMandriva LX 3.02 alongside Windows 10 on a HP Pavilion 15-aw009na with EFI boot system. I only get to the screen where I can choose between the options "Start OpenMandriva LX in live mode", "Install OpenMandriva Lx", etc. When I choose any of these options, the installer then throws the following error message, that is repeated all the time:

[number] Mandriva Linux installation AMD-Vi: completion-wait loop time out

I have double checked that the md5sum is correct, the iso is not corrupted, and had to disable the secure boot option in the bootloader (bios), but it is still not working.

Answer (score 0):

I'm using Ubuntu 18.04, upgraded from 17.10, and what worked for me was to sort of disable IOMMU in the kernel parameters with the following parameter: `iommu=soft`. I tried `iommu=off`, but it crashed the whole system, while leaving it as is only worked for a bit of time (until I enabled hardware virtualization, AMD-vi to be exact).